# Let $(2x^2 +3x+4)^{10} = \sum _{r=0}^{20} a_rx^r$. Then find $\frac{a_7}{a_{13}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem, multinomial-theorem

I tried using the multinomial theorem where the n’th term is

$$\frac{10!}{r_1!r_2!r_3!}\times 2^{r_1}3^{r_2} 4^{r_3} x^{2r_1 + r_2}$$
($r$ is an integer)

Where $$r_1+r_2+r_3=10$$ and
For first part ie. $a_7$
$$2r_1+r_2 =7$$

But I don’t have enough equations to solve for all the $r$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the nature of $r_i$s?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee they are integers

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238533/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method without finding coefficient**

given$$\color{blue}{(2x^2 +3x+4)^{10}} = \sum _{r=0}^{20} a_rx^r$$ replace $x\to \frac{2}{x}$  $$2^{10} \frac{{(2x^2+3x+4)}^{10}}{x^{20}}=\sum_{r=0}^{20} \frac{2^ra_r}{x^r}$$  $$\iff 2^{10}\color{blue}{{(2x^2+3x+4)}^{10}}=\sum_{r=0}^{20} 2^ra_r x^{20-r}$$ Now as this is an identity the coefficient of $x^7$ in the LHS should be same as in RHS $$2^{10}a_7=2^{13}a_{13}\implies \frac{a_7}{a_{13}}=?$$

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by it being an identity. I didn’t get anything after that statement

Comment: @Aditya It means it is true for all $x\in R$ as  I proved ,so the coefficient of $x^k$ in LHS is same in $RHS$

Comment: @Aditya think bout it like this the lHS is  a polynomial and the RHS is also the same polynomial as i have only subsituted and  done some manipulations so they have same coefficeints

Comment: How did u find coefficient of $x^7$ in LHS? I tried the multinomial theorem (in the question), but I didn’t get it

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore: a very cool approach. Awesome!

Comment: @NimaS thanks!${},{}$

Comment: Oh yeah, totally missed it. Smart answer!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore why are we able to use subtstitution , i mean we would need it to be having conditions satisfying like one-one ? Inverse exist or something ? Or are we able to do this everytime needed ? Without caring for conditions

Comment: @Orion_Pax I dont we have to check such conditions ,this is simply an identity so if it exists for x then it should exist for 1/x as well (except ofc for x=0 but that isnt important here)

Comment: I see , though can we say a given equation is identity if it doesnt satify at one point but satify others ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not going wrong. There are different ways to create $x^{7}$ term. For instance, you may choose $x^2$ once and choose $x$ five times (look at Case(II) below).

So, the goal is to find all possible ways to satisfy your equation. In other words:

$$Case(I): {r_{1} = 0}, \space {r_{2}=7} $$
$$Case(II): {r_{1} = 1}, \space {r_{2}=5} $$
$$Case(III): {r_{1} = 2}, \space {r_{2}=3} $$
$$Case(IV):  {r_{1} = 3}, \space {r_{2}=1} $$

Now, for each case, let's calculate the coefficient behind $x^7$:

$$Case(I): {10 \choose 0}{10 \choose 7}{3 \choose 3} \times {2^{0}} \times {3^{7}} \times {4^{3}} $$

Do the same things for other cases and then sum them together.